# Working with Java to create a program to calculate Quadratic Formula

Tags: java

So I am working on this program. Everything executes fine but the math is not right. If you input all 2,s you should get the result (0,0) but I am getting (1,-1). If I could get a fresh set of eyes to give me an idea as to where my calculations are wrong and what I did I would really appreciate it!

```
        System.out.println("Please enter the value for d: ");
        int d = IO.readInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the value for f: ");
        int f = IO.readInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the value for g: ");
        int g = IO.readInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the value for m: ");
        int m = IO.readInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the value for b: ");
        int b = IO.readInt();

    double y = (f - m);
    double u = (4*d*(g-b));
    double i = (2*d);
    double o = ((f+m)*(f+m));

  /*
         * x=(-(f-m)(+ or -)(sqrt((f-m)^2) - (4d(g-b))
         *                  2d
         * 
         * x=-b(+ or -)(sqrt((b^(2))-4ac))
         *              2a
         */

    double x = ((0-(y))+(Math.sqrt(o)-((u)))/(i));
    double x1 = ((0-(y))-(Math.sqrt(o)-((u)))/(i));

    IO.outputStringAnswer(x + " , " + x1);
```

Comment: You want to do `(Math.sqrt(o - u))`, not `(Math.sqrt(o)-((u)))`.

Comment: Have you tried printing out each value along the way, or using your IDE to debug? If you start with a simple example, such as "all 2's", you should pretty easily spot which intermediate term is going awry. If you can't find it there, try breaking your last two big lines of calculation into smaller steps and rinse/repeat.

Comment: Sizik, that worked. Why was that causing such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `o` value, it does not match your comment...

Comment: Between fixing the o and removing the extra parens around it; it is calculating properly now. Thank you for the help!